# XcodeKit extension cursor position

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-extension

I am creating for myself Xcode 8 extension with new `XcodeKit`. I get text with `XCSourceTextBuffer` and range with `XCSourceTextRange`. With that I have start and end position of selected text and I can append some text to beginning of the line. The problem is that I can't catch latest position of my cursor, I want to check position of cursor so I can insert text there, not at where my line begins. Does anyone know how to handle that?

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out how to get the cursor position in XcodeKit?